# Tensorflowjs: Error: Unknown layer: Conv2DTranspose

Tags: keras, tensorflow.js

When I import my model in Tensorflowjs (`yarn watch` in the working directory),I get the error:

```
"Error: Unknown layer: Conv2DTranspose".
```

When running the conversion from keras model to tfjs, there is no error.

According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/53), conv2dtranspose is now supported in tensorflow.js.
So, not sure why I get the error.
Thank you

Comment: Are you using the latest tfjs version?

Comment: How do I check the tfjs version? I ran `yarn add @tensorflow/tfjs-node` , which shows: `@tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.7`....would `0.1.7` be the tfjs version?

Comment: Yes, the current one is 0.11.6

Comment: Thank you. What's the command line to upgrade to the latest version? When I try `yarn add @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.11.6`, I get the option to choose between version `0.1.0` thru `0.1.7`. There is no option to choose `0.11.6`

Comment: OK, got it! The version update is done in `package.json` file at the line: `"dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "0.11.6",` Thank you!

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Yep. Thanks a lot for the tip. Looks like another layer in my model is not supported though (`BilinearUpSampling2D`)

Comment: There is [upSampling2d](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#layers.upSampling2d) which could replace it.